# Given that a matrix is PSD, can we show whether this function is strictly convex?

Tags: matrices, convex-analysis, positive-semidefinite

For this problem it's given that $Q\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ is positive semi-definite, and now I'm trying to figure out whether 
$$g(x) = \sqrt{x^TQx-1}$$
is convex over $\mathbb{R}^n$

I did a similar problem where the $-1$ in the function was just replaced with a $+1$, and I found that that function was convex. Using similar methods, I've been unable to show whether g is convex, let alone strictly convex.

Any suggestions about methods to use here would be much appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: $g(x)$ may not be defined at some points. For example it is not defined at $x = 0$ (zero vector). This may affect the convexity, because the domain of definition itself is not convex.

Comment: If $v^T Q v = 1$ and you take $x = t v$, you'll get $g(tv) = \sqrt{t^2-1}$ which is concave where it is real.